# Left join with where clause not working

Tags: join, ms-access-2007, left-join

I was trying to get `only selected rows from table A`(not all rows) and `rows matching table A from table B`, but it shows only matching rows from table A and table B, excluding rest of the selected rows from table A.
I used this condition,

```
SELECT A.CategoryName,B.discount
    from A LEFT JOIN B ON A.CategoryCode = B.CategoryCode 
    WHERE A.itemtype='F' and B.party_code=2
```

i have 2 tables:
table 1: `A` with 3 columns
CategoryName,CategoryCode(PK),ItemType
table 2: `B` with 2 columns
CategoryCode(FK),Discount,PartyCode(FK)(`from another table`)

NOTE: working in access 2007

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-matching rows from table B, party_code = NULL, so your where clause will evaluate to false and therefore the row won't be returned. So, you need to filter the "B" records before joining. Try

```
SELECT A.CategoryName,B.discount
    from A LEFT JOIN B ON A.CategoryCode = B.CategoryCode  and B.party_code=2 
    WHERE A.itemtype='F'
```

[EDIT] That doesn't work in Access. next try.

You can create a query to do your filter. Let's call it "B_filtered". This is just

```
SELECT * FROM B where party_code = 2
```

(You could make the "2" a parameter to make it more flexible).

Then, just use this query in your actual query.

```
SELECT A.CategoryName,B_filtered.discount
    from A LEFT JOIN B_filtered ON A.CategoryCode = B_filtered.CategoryCode 
    WHERE A.itemtype='F'
```

[EDIT]

Just Googled - I think you can do this directly with a subquery.

```
SELECT A.CategoryName,B_filtered.discount
        from A LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM B where party_code = 2) AS B_filtered ON A.CategoryCode = B_filtered.CategoryCode 
        WHERE A.itemtype='F'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But it doesn't works. It gives error that `JOIN expression not supported`.

Comment: so you are saying that i should create another B_filtered table?

Comment: No - in Access you can create a query and save it. Then you can use _that_ query in other queries (just like you would a table)... and if you use a parameter in the first query, you can extract any party_code you want...

Comment: Yes it works. But how can we do it without creating a separate query.?

Answer (score 1):

What mlinth proposed is correct, and would work for most other SQL languages. The query below is the same basic concept but using a null condition.

Try:

```
SELECT A.CategoryName,B.discount
from A LEFT JOIN B ON A.CategoryCode = B.CategoryCode 
WHERE A.itemtype='F'   and (B.party_code=2 OR B.party_code IS NULL)
```

If party_code is nullable, switch to using the PK or another non-nullable field.

Comment: It worked, but partially.Now it shows some rows but still some are missing. For eg: if there are 15 rows of type `A.itemtype='F'` ,it shows only 10 rows, 5 are missing.

Comment: Yes. other 5 don't have anything related to party_code 2.

Comment: Should A be showing without B, if B.Party_Code = 2?